# .net core - builds are too frequent and too slow

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm pretty new to .net core and to visual studio code as well.
I'm building an asp.net WebAPI project and i use entity framework core for the database layer.

I have two problems:

1. Builds are too frequent - whenever i run the web server (F5), it builds (even if the code hasn't changed). Creating/Applying entity framework migrations also builds even if the code hasn't changed.
2. Builds are very slow, often taking up to a minute to finish. I remember working on much larger projects in Visual Studio 2015 and .NET Framework 4.5 and the builds were much faster. I know that i'm not giving too much information here, but maybe someone is familiar with this one?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Projects will only be built if something has changed or you override that setting (e.g. with the `--no-incremental` setting) or if something has changed in the output directory.

Comment: @DavidG Sounds reasonable but it's not the case, every time i run (F5) or run a migration, it rebuilds.

Comment: Have you made any changes that might cause this?

Comment: @DavidG No, I've just reproduced it, i stopped the debug session and ran it again (without touching anything else)

Comment: No special configuration of dotnet? Does it do it with another fresh project?

Comment: @DavidG I couldn't replicate it with a fresh dotnet project. Could it be that something is wrong in my project's configuration?

Comment: It would appear that way. Do you have any custom build script or a global.json file, anything else?

Comment: No, just the default tasks.json that points to my csproj. Perhaps I'll try to copy the source code to a new dotnet project and see if it solves anything.

Comment: `tasks.json` isn't a default file, what is in it?

Comment: @DavidG it's generated by vscode, https://codepaste.net/e02w7g